# ANTLR4 comments, preprocessor or directives parsing

Tags: parsing, delphi, antlr4

I need to parse Delphi directives in ANTLR4. For example,

```
{$MODE Delphi}{$ifdef net}
net,
{$else}
NewKernel,
{$ifndef st}
{$ifndef neter}
hyper,
{$endif}
{$endif}
{$endif}
```

But simultaneously, in Delphi there are inside curly braces { } could be comments. So, How to create ANTLR4 grammar, which is working something like this: "file: not to parse text { parsing } not to parse text ;" ?

Comment: So you want to parse the comments in a delphi file?

Comment: Compiler directives always starts with `{$` and ends with `}` (or possibly `(*$` and `*)`). Comments can not have the `$` sign in the 2nd (or 3rd) position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to be certain from how the Q is phrased. Sounds like you are looking for:

```
directive : LDrctv .... RBrace ; // replace .... with appropriate rule terms
comment   : LBrace .*? RBrace  ;
skip      : . ; // aggregates all tokens not included in above rules

LDrctv : '{$' ;
LBrace : '{'  ;
RBrace : '}'  ;

// other token rules
```

Update: the `skip` rule catches all tokens that are not consumed by the other rules. If only the `directive` rule is of interest, then only the corresponding `DirectiveContext` nodes in the parse tree need be evaluated.

Comment: And how to skip text, which is out of curvy braces?
 `implementation
 
{$R *.dfm}

uses NcFrameEngine, NfErrorDlg; `

Comment: Updated the answer.